some parameters with wrong summatory
I create a table in looker studio with the parameters: date, country, device category, views, sessions and total users, the summatory in looker studio specifically in sessions and total users are wrong, I verify this exporting the data and doing the summatory manually in excel. It also happens in the report of GA4, so there is a solution to this issue?

I did the summatory of the columns using excel but the results doesn't match, also tried another methods to export the data like format, downloading the reports in GA4, looker studio, even google sheets using an extension

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

If you apply a dimension to the number of users and sessions, you will have a series of rows in which the total number of users and sessions is not the algebraic sum of the values of the individual rows. This is normal and known behaviour for GA4.
Also in Universal Analytics, the total number of users was not the sum of the values of the individual rows.
I provide you an example:
User 'Foo' visited page 'A' and page 'B':

So you will have 1 user, 1 session and 2 pageviews.
If I split report by page I will have:
Page A: 1 user, 1 session, 1 pageview
Page B: 1 user, 1 session, 1 pageview

If I do the sum of the rows I get:
2 users, 2 sessions, 2 page views

So, the sum cannot be done. To get the total number of users and sessions, simply query these metrics, without dividing by other dimensions.
